# call function when last vim instance is closing

Tags: vim

Is it possible to perform an action (call a function) when the last instance of vim is closed?
The event `VimLeave` seems to be executed when any vim instance is closing, and thus is not what I need.

Idea?

Comment: I am not sure there is a built-in method for this. Try external syncronization like checking ``pgrep vim`` status in `VimLeave`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I suppose that will not work on windows though.

Comment: Vim instances have no practical knowledge of each other so yeah, you'll need to use an external program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As romainl stated, this is not possible.

You could use an external program or some text file to keep track of the number of open instances (maybe incrementing upon `VimEnter` and decrementing on `VimLeave`.

But you should consider using a single Vim instance - some arguments are described [in this video.](http://vimeo.com/4446112)